# ksh, perform action when reaching loop maximal value

Tags: shell, ksh

I am looking to write a small korn shell script doing 5 tests (by waiting some time before each one) and then, if they all fail, performing an action.

I was looking at doing something like :

```
    for i in {1..5}
    do
       "doMyTest"             #it fills a variables "status" (but can unfortunately fails)
       if [ "$status" ]; then #if status is filled then we can leave the loop
          break
       fi
       sleep 3                #else wait some time before doing another try
    done

    if [ -z "$status" ]; then
       exit 1
    fi

... then the rest of my program
```

Do you have any idea how could I do this in a better way ? 
It sounds a bit redundant ...

Comment: can you explain why is not correct? with the current implementation after a max of 5 "failed" executions it ends.

Comment: Actually, my code is bigger than just this test, I have many more lines after. But I want them to be only executed if the status has been retrieved in 5 tries.

Comment: That's more or less how I'd do it. Set a flag within the loop, then check that flag outside the loop.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Run some code if all 5 iterations of the loop were executed? Run some code if the loop broke out early? Exit the script if `doMyTest` fails?

Comment: Also appears on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785701/ksh-perform-action-when-reaching-loop-maximal-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set --
while [ "$(($#>5))" -eq "-${#status}" ]
do    "test"; ${status:+":"} sleep 3
      set '' "$@"
done
```

If you test by complement you can often do a lot more with one test.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid to double-check `$status` by doing it like this:

```
for i in {1..5}
do
   "doMyTest"                 #it fills a variables "status" (but can unfortunately fails)
   if [ -n "$status" ]; then  #if status is filled then we can leave the loop
      break
   elif [ $i -eq 5 ]; then
       exit 1                 #all the tests failed, exiting
   fi
   sleep 3                    #else wait some time before doing another try
done
```

Answer (score 0):

My Accepted answer on SO:
If you only want to see a failure when all tests fail? When you can skip the other tests when one test succeeds, you can use

```
test1 || sleep 3 && \
   test2 || sleep 3 && \
   test3 || sleep 3 && \
   test4 || sleep 3 && \
   test5 || exit 1
```